# How enable view icon "Show Blueprint"?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I did Getting Start Android https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#open

and in 4 paragraph I had a problem

4.Click Show Blueprint  so only the blueprint layout is visible.

But I did not found this icon(button) "Show Blueprint".

```
Ubuntu 16.04
Android Studio 2.1
JRE 1.8.0_131
jvm 64 bit
```

atached screen
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was introduced in Android Studio 2.2, so you will have to upgrade your installation.